# What is the purpose of writing XML version?

Tags: xml, version

I'm new to XML, I want to understand the basic.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

In that above code of xml, what is the purpose of

> version="1.0"

I understand that this is XML version. but the question is

*What is the purpose?*

coz I searched, but I wasn't found an answer to clarify this to me. 
Can anyone help me, if this was a duplicate can you please comment the link.
Thanks you Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Version
>
> Specifies the version of the XML standard that the XML document
> conforms to. The version attribute must be included if the XML
> declaration is declared well-formedness constraint

The ﬁrst line in an XML document is called the prolog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
```

Declaring the XML version is especially important now that XML 1.1 has been approved as a W3C Recommendation. XML 1.1 changes the definition of well-formedness in small but definite ways. One nice change is that XML 1.1 makes the XML declaration mandatory. The recommendation states:
XML 1.1 documents MUST begin with an XML declaration which specifies the version of XML being used.
The emphasis is mine. By definition, any XML document without a declaration is an XML 1.0 document. However, you should never leave the version unstated, especially since it is also very important to specify the encoding.

Comment: if it has @MichaelAdam then mark it as ticked so other people who want to know the same as you can find it easily and quickly :)

Comment: I just forgot or i thought i ticked it already.  by the way ty for reminding, especially for Josh